# How to add the same object type to java Map using generics

Tags: java, generics

I have two objects as follows

```
public class MyObject1 implements Serializable
{

private Long id;
... other properties and getters and setters
}

public class MyObject2 extends MyObject1
{
private String name;
...other properties and getters and setters
}

MyObject1 obj1 = new MyObject1();
MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2();
```

How do i add these two instances in a HashMap using generics?

**Update**

I want to be able to add MyObject1 and MyObject2 in the same map.
Like

```
Map<Long, ? extends MyObject1> map;
```

so that i can do this

```
map.put(obj1);
map.put(obj2);
```

Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: In a Map, you map key to object. What is key, what is object in your case?

Comment: You cannot have `add(Object)` (one parameter method) in `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the id is the key. It would be something like this:

```
Map<Long, MyObject1> map = new HashMap<Long, MyObject1>();
map.add(obj1.getId(), obj1);
map.add(obj2.getId(), obj2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use `Map<Long, MyObject1>`:

```
Map<Long, MyObject1> map = new HashMap<Long, MyObject1>();
map.put(1l, new MyObject1());
map.put(2l, new MyObject2());
```

Note:

`? extends MyObject1` is a wildcard. It stands for "some unknown type, and the only thing we know about it is it's a subtype of Object". It's fine in the declaration but you can't instantiate it because it's not an actual type.

Comment: Okay, so my answer is wrong. So what is the difference between declaring the map as `Map<Long, ? extends MyObject1>` and `Map<Long, MyObject1>`

Comment: In the first case, there is some _fixed_ but _unknown_ type that extends `MyObject1` that is actually the value type.  So, for example, you can assign a `Map<Long, MyObject2>` to a `Map<Long, ? extends MyObject1>`.  (And this is why your solution wouldn't have worked: because Java stops you from `put`ting a `MyObject1` into a map that might only accept `MyObject2`.)

Comment: @louiswasserman, Sure, but when would you use one rather than the other.

Comment: Always use `Map<Long, MyObject1>`, unless you're receiving the map from somewhere else, and want to allow a `Map<Long, MyObject2>`.